# How to prevent parent component from re-rendering with React (next.js) SSR two-pass rendering?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

So I have a SSR app using Next.js. I am using a 3rd party component that utilizes WEB API so it needs to be loaded on the client and not the server. I am doing this with 'two-pass' rendering which I read about here: https://itnext.io/tips-for-server-side-rendering-with-react-e42b1b7acd57

I'm trying to figure out why when 'ssrDone' state changes in the next.js page state the entire `<Layout>` component unnecessarily re-renders which includes the page's Header, Footer, etc.

I've read about `React.memo()` as well as leveraging `shouldComponentUpdate()` but I can't seem to prevent it from re-rendering the `<Layout>` component.

My console.log message for the `<Layout>` fires twice but the `<ThirdPartyComponent>` console message fires once as expected. Is this an issue or is React smart enough to not actually update the DOM so I shouldn't even worry about this. It seems silly to have it re-render my page header and footer for no reason.

In the console, the output is:

```
Layout rendered
Layout rendered
3rd party component rendered
```

index.js (next.js page)

```
import React from "react";
import Layout from "../components/Layout";
import ThirdPartyComponent from "../components/ThirdPartyComponent";

class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ssrDone: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ ssrDone: true });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Layout>
        {this.state.ssrDone ? <ThirdPartyComponent /> : <div> ...loading</div>}
      </Layout>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

ThirdPartyComponent.jsx

```
import React from "react";

export default function ThirdPartyComponent() {
  console.log("3rd party component rendered");
  return <div>3rd Party Component</div>;
}
```

Layout.jsx

```
import React from "react";

export default function Layout({ children }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {console.log("Layout rendered")}
      NavBar here
      <div>Header</div>
      {children}
      <div>Footer</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you could do, is define a new `<ClientSideOnlyRenderer />` component, that would look like this:

```js
const ClientSideOnlyRenderer = memo(function ClientSideOnlyRenderer({
  initialSsrDone = false,
  renderDone,
  renderLoading,
}) {
  const [ssrDone, setSsrDone] = useState(initialSsrDone);

  useEffect(
    function afterMount() {
      setSsrDone(true);
    },
    [],
  );

  if (!ssrDone) {
    return renderLoading();
  }

  return renderDone();
});
```

And you could use it like this:

```js
class Home extends React.Component {
  static async getInitialProps({ req }) {
    return {
      isServer: !!req,
    };
  };

  renderDone() {
    return (
      <ThirdPartyComponent />
    );
  }
  renderLoading() {
    return (<div>Loading...</div>);
  }

  render() {
    const { isServer } = this.props;

    return (
      <Layout>
        <ClientSideOnlyRenderer
          initialSsrDone={!isServer}
          renderDone={this.renderDone}
          renderLoading={this.renderLoading}
        />
      </Layout>
    );
  }
}
```

This way, only the `ClientSideOnlyRenderer` component gets re-rendered after initial mount.

Comment: This seems like the right approach, but I run your code and the console.log inside `<Layout>` still runs twice (renders twice?) just as my example does?

Comment: @TaylorA.Leach I edited my covde, I forgot the remove the old code in the Home component

Comment: Ah right so removing the state from the page and passing it down to the HOC prevents the page from re-rendering the entire `<Layout>` and instead now correctly only renders the `<ThirdPartyComponent>`. I knew that was the answer I just couldn't quite get there. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The `Layout` component re-renders because its `children` prop changed. First it was `<div> ...loading</div>` (when `ssrDone = false`) then `<ThirdPartyComponent />`  (when `ssrDone = true`)

Comment: But my question was is there a way for me to prevent the unnecessarily re-render since the only thing that will be changing is the ThirdPartyComponent.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue recently, what you can do is to use redux to store the state that is causing the re-render of the component.

Then with useSelector and shallowEqual you can use it and change its value without having to re-render the component.

Here is an example

```
import styles from "./HamburgerButton.module.css";
import { useSelector, shallowEqual } from "react-redux";
const selectLayouts = (state) => state.allLayouts.layouts[1];

export default function HamburgerButton({ toggleNav }) {
    let state = useSelector(selectLayouts, shallowEqual);
    let navIsActive = state.active;
    console.log("navIsActive", navIsActive); // true or false

const getBtnStyle = () => {
    if (navIsActive) return styles["hamBtn-active"];
    else return styles["hamBtn"];
};

return (
    <div
        id={styles["hamBtn"]}
        className={getBtnStyle()}
        onClick={toggleNav}
    >
        <div className={styles["stick"]}></div>
    </div>
);
}
```

This is an animated button component that toggles a sidebar, all wrapped inside a header component (parent)

Before i was storing the sidebar state in the header, and on its change all the header has to re-render causing problems in the button animation.

Instead i needed all my header, the button state and the sidebar to stay persistent during the navigation, and to be able to interact with them without any re-render.

I guess now the state is not in the component anymore but "above" it, so next doesn't start a re-render. (i can be wrong about this part but it looks like it)

Note that toggleNav is defined in header and passed as prop because i needed to use it in other components as well. Here is what it looks like:

```
 const toggleNav = () => {
    dispatch(toggleLayout({ id: "nav", fn: "toggle" }));
}; //toggleLayout is my redux action
```

I'm using an id and fn because all my layouts are stored inside an array in redux, but you can use any logic or solution for this part.